# Connect to HTTP server via Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I have server component which connects to a remote server via HTTP(s) and gets some response. Can I connect to such a server side code in a java plugin if I am using Phonegap for Android ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use xmlHttpRequest method of javascript to get the response from server or 
you can use **jquery** plugin http://jquery.com/ in your app and play with ajax function of jquery.

```
$.ajax({  
   url:'stringURL',  
   beforeSend: function(x) {      
     x.setRequestHeader('Authorization','username/pwd');  
   },  
   dataType:"xml",  
   contentType:'application/xml',  
   timeout:10000,  
   type:'POST',  
   success:function(data) {  
     alert(data);  
   },  
   error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {     
     alert("Error status :"+textStatus);  
     alert("Error type :"+errorThrown);  
     alert("Error message :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);  
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using angular '$http' for such requests as well.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Angular works really well with phonegap due to the single-page nature.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can all you have to do is edit your java file and put in the url of your http request

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you whitelist the URL(s) that you're connecting too (otherwise you won't be able to connect out from the device)...or if you're using Phonegap Build (build.phonegap.com), which is certainly worth a look if you're just starting out, you'll need to tweak the config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in your function :-

```
 var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                                        xmlhttp.overrideMimeType("application/json");
                                        xmlhttp.open("POST",ipAddress +"/create_account.php",true);
                                        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                                        xmlhttp.send("email="+emailId+"&password="+password);
                                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                                        {
                                            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
                                                console.log("Registration response: "+xmlhttp.response);
                                                var resp = "(" + xmlhttp.response.toString() + ")";
                                                var jsondata=eval(resp);
                                                if(jsondata.status == false){

                                                        navigator.notification.confirm(jsondata.message,onConfirmOne,'Duplicate Email',['Ok']);

                                                }else{

                                                }/*end else*/
                                            }/* end readystate*/

                                        }/*end function */
```