# Phonegap-Android Login Authentication App

Tags: android, http, cordova, https

Do not mistake me if my question silly. Since I already worked much, but could not make it.

I am trying to develop app which can work in cross platform. I have started developing  for android using phonegap.  In that I have following confusion. I am using ECLIPSE as IDE

1. What is  difference between  cordova-2.2.0.js and phonegap-1.2.js.
   Since When I use this tutorial [examples](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) . It instructs , we need to load cordova.js
   but In some of the sites they have given the example  with phonegap.js
2. And also I need to make http communication to my server . Whether I could achieve with these above java script files. Or I need to go with some other plugins.
3. Which one I really suppose to load in my code cordova or phonegap.

Please guide me on this to go further

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

1. Apache Products : `Cordova`(2.0) is just an update of `phonegap`(1.2). You can use either anyone of them. Better to use the latest.
2. You can make `HTTP connection` with the server using Ajax calling methods.

See the documentation of Cordova [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/index.html)

Comment: thanks, I try to use ajax post method to reach my server. But it is not at all reaching my server.Can you provide me some straight forward reference on http communication

Comment: see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219569/connect-to-http-server-via-phonegap